# why strncpy is able to copy source string even if destination buffer is zero?

Tags: c, buffer, strcpy, strncpy

```
int main() {
    char src[] = "santosh";
    char dest[0];
    strncpy(dest, src, 4);
    printf("%s\n", dest); // expecting o/p "sant" but o/p was "santtosh"
    int i = 0;
    while (dest[i]) {
        printf("%c", dest[i]);   //expecting output "sant" but it was "santtosh"
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    i = 0;

    while (src[i]) {
        printf("%c", src[i]); // expecting o/p "santosh" but it was "anttosh"
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am having trouble with this code, I run the code using gcc compiler and here is output I got(comment section). Why behavior is not as per the expectation? why `strncpy()` is able to copy source string even if dest buff is not enough?

Comment: `char dest[0]` <- pretty much your entire program is undefined behaviour at this point. What you're saying with that declaration is that the `dest` array is a *fixed* size of 0 characters. Therefore it can never contain anything and any access to it (read *or* write) is undefined.

Comment: Named after a British pop band **UB40**... You should also consider removing the `c++` tag.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. C will let you write anywhere you want, and it's up to you to decide if you should...

Comment: drive on the wrong side of the road, you could survive a few minutes. But it doesn't mean that it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: Even if the target buffer was big enough, this use of `strncpy` would be wrong. Before you use `strncpy` read about and understand what it does. It is **not** a "safe" replacement for `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes undefined behavior, trying to explain why it produces some output or another is pointless.

Here are the problems:

- You do not include `<stdio.h>`, nor `<string.h>`. Calling functions that have not been previously defined is not OK.  Include the proper header file to avoid undefined behavior.
- `char dest[0];` defines an array with a size of `0`. Such an object cannot be accessed, not even its address is meaningful. `gcc` and `clang` allow this, but as an extension to the C Standard.  This definition looks like a typo, use `gcc -Wall -W` or `clang -Weverything` to enable useful warnings that will prevent such silly bugs.
- `strncpy(dest, src, 4);` invokes undefined behavior since the length of `dest` is less than `4`. Note that the behavior would still be error prone if `dest` had a length of `4` since `strncpy` would not null terminate the destination array if the source string's length is greater or equal to the size argument. Here `"santosh"` has a length of `7`, so `dest` would hold the characters `s`, `a`, `n` and `t`, but no null terminator.  Your `while` loop would invoke undefined behavior as `while (dest[i])` would access `dest` beyond its size.  `strncpy()` is error prone, its semantics are widely misunderstood and cause bugs very easily. **Do not use this function**.
- As explained above, `while (dest[i])` invokes undefined behavior because `dest` cannot be dereferenced as currently defined or even if it were defined as `char dest[4];`.

Here is an improved version, using `snprintf()` and `strncat()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char src[] = "santosh";
    char dest[5];

    *dest = '\0';
    strncat(dest, src, 4);
    printf("%s\n", dest);        // will output "sant"
    for (int i = 0; dest[i]; i++) {
        printf("%c", dest[i]);   // will output "sant" too
    }
    printf("\n");

    snprintf(dest, sizeof dest, "%s", src);
    printf("%s\n", dest);        // will output "sant"
    for (int i = 0; dest[i]; i++) {
        printf("%c", dest[i]);   // will output "sant" again
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; src[i]; i++) {
        printf("%c", src[i]);    // will output "santosh"
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```